# Use Javascript to get the source code of another website using a URL

Tags: javascript, html, url

How can I use JavaScript to view the html source code of a website using a URL

Comment: If you have a CORS proxy, it's pretty easy. Otherwise it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that you are looking for :

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://www.somesite.com/',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(res) {
      var data = $.parseHTML(res);  //<----try with $.parseHTML().
      // data you will get full html code from given url

      // this is how you can fetch any element from html that fetched from url
      $(data).find('div.content').each(function(){
          $('#here').append($(this).html());
     });

   }
 });
```

> Note : This is assuming that the website enables CORS which is pretty
>   uncommon for most sites in general.( as Patrick Roberts said. Thanks for this point :) )

Comment: This is assuming that the website [enables CORS](https://enable-cors.org/) which is pretty uncommon for most sites in general.

Comment: Yes thanks for that , let me add this as note @PatrickRoberts